# Beginner SQL Developer questions

Tags: sql

So I am currently in a DBMS class, and we are doing a section on SQL.  It basically consists of me creating a database for 5 guests staying at a hotel.  There are 8 tables with information (Tables listed below). I currently have all the info for the tables entered and working (not included below), but am stuck on a few queries that we are required to write for the assignment.

The query that I am stuck on: Don't even really know where to start on this one.

1. Name of guests who have incurred charges for golf and dinner in the
   same itinerary.

Any help would be appreciated.  I know I didn't include the actual data used for each table below, so let me know if you need any other information that may help to write the queries.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
1.GUEST (GUESTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDINIT, STRADDR, CITY, STATE, ZIP, PHONE, EMAIL, AGE)

2.RESERVATION  RESID, RESDATETIME, CHECKINDATE, CHECKOUTDATE, ROOMTYPE, TOTALCOST, GUESTID)

3.CREDITCARD (CCNO, TYPE, EXPIRYDATE, GUESTID)

4.ITINERARY (ITINID, CHECKINDATETIME, CHECKOUTDATETIME, ADULTCOUNT, CHILDCOUNT, GUESTID, ROOMNO)

5.ROOM (ROOMNO, ROOMTYPE, DAILYRATE, AMENITIES)

6.BILL (BILLID, BILLDATE, AMOUNTDUE, ITINID, CCNO)

7.CHARGETYPE (CHARGEID, DESCRIPTION)

8.CHARGES (CHARGEID, ITINID, CHARGEDATETIME, AMOUNT, GUESTID)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. And please specify which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, ...)

Comment: Sorry about that, I believe I am using the Oracle DBMS.  I'm pretty stuck on both of these, so haven't tried much.  For question 1 I've tried:  select * from charges where charges.amount>(select AVG(amount) from charge).  And I have no idea of where to start for question 2.

Comment: did your professor clarify what "relevant details" are?

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments.  Please [edit] your question instead, where you can post properly formatted code and add relevant tags. Putting the info in comments means people don't see it when reading your question, and properly tagging means it can be found in future searches using that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a homework assignment, I don't want to just post the answer, but I have good clues for you.

**Question 1**: You'll need to make an internal select statement (subquery) to determine the average charge across all charges before you can compare against each charge. Your subquery might look something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(AMOUNT) "AvgCharge" FROM CHARGES
```

You could put this in the SELECT portion of your statement or as a [Cartesian product](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html).

**Question 2**: I'm guessing you'll need to join the `ITINERARY`, `CHARGES`, and `CHARGETYPE` tables together.  Here's a link for [JOINs in Oracle](http://www.asktheoracle.net/oracle-sql-joins.html).  Afterwords, you'll have to limit that statement to only show golf and dinner charges.

Comment: I ended up getting getting the first question solved, but still do not really have any idea of how to do the one still listed above.  I know I was given a hint here, but really am not too familiar with SQL syntax.  Any more help from anyone would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. The first thing you need is the name of teh guest. Well clearly that has to come fromteh guest table.

so you have

```
select FIRSTNAME, MIDINIT,  LASTNAME, 
From Guest
```

Now you only want guests with Itineraries so you do an inner join to Itinerary  (hint you join on GuestID)

```
 select FIRSTNAME, MIDINIT,  LASTNAME, ItineraryID
    From Guest
 JOIN ITINERARY on GUEST.GUESTID =  ITINERARY.GUESTID
```

Now you only want guests who have charges for that ITINERARY.

So you would think to  join to CHARGES and CHARGETYPE (to get the type of charges) and use a where clause to limit the charges to the types you are interested in. But becasue you want to make sure you have both types of charges, you need to join to CHARGES and CHARGETYPE twice (I don't know about Oracle but in SQL server these would need to be aliased (I would call them C1 and CT1 and C2 and CT2) I would suspect the same for Oracle). The first join will have a where clause of CT1 = 'dinner' and the second grouping of the two tables would include a where clause of CT2 = 'golf'